# Using Linq for given scenario

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am new to LINQ, my TL gave me an requirement, i can able to complete that in few seconds since it's a basic one, i want that code to be converted in to LINQ, please help me out.

```
foreach (var item in query)
            {
                profileSearchResultEntity = new ProfileSearchResultEntity();
                profileSearchResultEntity.Id = item.ProfileId;

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DisplayName))
                {
                    profileSearchResultEntity.Name = item.LastName + "," + " " + item.FirstName;
                }
                else
                {
                    profileSearchResultEntity.Name = item.LastName + "," + " " + item.FirstName +" "+"-"+" "+ item.DisplayName;
                }     


                lstProfileSearchResultEntity.Add(profileSearchResultEntity);
            }
            return lstProfileSearchResultEntity;
```

How this condition can be satisfied using LINQ or Lambda????

Answer (score 1):

```
var lstProfileSearchResultEntity = 
    query.Select(i => new ProfileSearchResultEntity 
        {
            Id = i.Id,
            Name = i.LastName + "," + " " + i.FirstName + 
                       (string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.DisplayName) ? "" : " - " + i.DisplayName)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks lot for the reply Anthony, now i started using LINQ Extension Methods which help for batch queries to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
   return query.Select(item =>
                     {

                         var profileSearchResultEntity = new ProfileSearchResultEntity{Id = item.ProfileId};
                         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DisplayName))
                         {
                             profileSearchResultEntity.Name = item.LastName + "," + " " + item.FirstName;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             profileSearchResultEntity.Name = item.LastName + "," + " " + item.FirstName + " " +
                                                              "-" + " " + item.DisplayName;
                         }
                         return profileSearchResultEntity;
                     });
```

I want to show that you can code a function to initialize new selected objects.

Comment: Thanks lot Brad for the reply.